# Code Compiler in PowerPoint

Tags: office365, powerpoint, add-in, presentation

I'm giving a presentation on c++ and am wondering if PowerPoint has a way to run a debugger in it?

Id like to show my audience a snippet of code and walk through it allowing them to see how the variables behave as we progress through the code, rather than closing down the slideshow and opening up a compiler.

Any add-ins or built-in functionality to support this type of presentation?

Comment: No; there's just the VBA IDE, which wouldn't help at all. You could run the presentation in windowed mode rather than kiosk or full screen, then size the slide show window and your IDE's debugger so they both appear on screen; click on whichever one you want to bring to front.  Or run both full screen and ALT+TAB between them as needed.

Comment: Found an answer to my question: http://pythontutor.com/

Also comes with a Microsoft add-in. but since the compilers for c&c++ are still experimental they are not supported in the add-in they are not supported via the add-in. 
A workaround for this is using the "Action" button on the Insert tab and choosing "mouse click" to open a browser window the full web application.

Thanks for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer to my question:

pythontutor.com

Also comes with a Microsoft add-in, but since the compilers for c&c++ are still experimental in the add-in they are not supported via the add-in yet.
A workaround for this is using the "Action" button on the Insert tab and choosing "mouse click" to open a browser window the full web application.

Thanks for your suggestions though.

Comment: This is 1) so cool and 2) exactly what I need. It's great because it's not just an online code compiler - it actually "demonstrates"/"teaches"/shows/hints at something really profound happening and/or described by code when it's actually running! Love it - thanks!! Will be using on the big screen for a beginners intro to code!